# HTTP Proxy - No further requests after respond to CONNECT

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, https, http-proxy

I've created an HTTP Proxy with PHP. It works well for simple HTTP requests, but in the case of TLS requests, when a client sends a `CONNECT` request, my proxy responds to the request with a 200 status and empty body but unlike expected, no further requests are made from the client.

Am I missing something or do TLS connections use something other than regular HTTP requests such as a socket connection?

Comment: Likely something is wrong with your processing of CONNECT. Probably missing something in the response so that the client is still waiting for the proxy to finish the response. But since you don't show any code it is impossible to say what is wrong with your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: After a `CONNECT` response, the server is expected to pass through the client's connection to the thing it is connecting to. There are no more HTTP requests or responses at that point, only unstructured data that you shouldn't attempt to parse.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks, can you give me a hint on how can this be done? Should I use a socket connection? Right now my proxy only receives the request, passes it to the target, passes the target's response to the client and closes the connection.

Comment: @RezaNooralizadeh CONNECT is not a request for the target which the proxy passes along - it is a request for the proxy to do something. It tells the proxy: please connect to this address with TCP and then pass along all data in both directions.

Comment: @user253751 Yes but how can I pass the data in both directions? Should I use socket?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in PHP, sorry, as I got here because of the HTTP part of the question, not the PHP part